# QT: unresolved external symbol while trying to get webpage source code

Tags: qt, html, symbols, unresolved-external

I started developing with Qt and I'm trying to get webpage source code. Here's what I have :

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QString>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

/**/

class GetHTMLSource : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    GetHTMLSource();
    void GetSource();

public slots:
    void GetDone(QNetworkReply*);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* NetManager;
};


GetHTMLSource::GetHTMLSource()
{
    NetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(NetManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
         this, SLOT(GetDone(QNetworkReply*)));

}

void GetHTMLSource::GetSource()
{
    NetManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com")));
}

void GetHTMLSource::GetDone(QNetworkReply* ReplyIn)
{

    QByteArray DataIn=ReplyIn->readAll();
    QString DataString(DataIn);

    //process str any way you like!

}

/**/

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    GetHTMLSource Test;
    Test.GetSource();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.pro

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = TestGetPageSource
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

QT += network
```

Errors are :

> mainwindow.obj:-1: error:LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall
>   GetHTMLSource::metaObject(void)const "
>   (?metaObject@GetHTMLSource@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
>
> mainwindow.obj:-1: error:LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual void * __thiscall GetHTMLSource::qt_metacast(char const *)"
>   (?qt_metacast@GetHTMLSource@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
>
> mainwindow.obj:-1: error:LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual int __thiscall GetHTMLSource::qt_metacall(enum
>   QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_metacall@GetHTMLSource@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)

Comment: quick and dirty solution: add `#include "mainwindow.moc"` at the end of mainwindow.cpp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you create classes derived from `QObject` you have to put them in separate header and source files.

So one .h and one .cpp file for one class.

Comment: @dj8000 Did you remember to add GetHTMLSource.h and GetHTMLSource.cpp to your .pro file?  Your errors are occurring because Qt's Meta Object Compiler (moc) is not running on GetHTMLSource.

Comment: Yes it has been added to "SOURCES" and "HEADERS" automatically. Errors still occurs.

Comment: Thats not true. You can put QObject based classes inside cpp files as well

Comment: @KamilKlimek Of course you can, but to do so you have to include file generated by moc in your cpp. So general rule is to separate QObject derived class to .h and .cpp file.

Comment: @MichK I wouldn't go so far that "general rule is to seperate QObjects to h/cpp files". Put Your classess where you need to. If you need to hide some implementation details, put them in .cpp file and include what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it on my own. Of course it was my stupid mistake.

In class definition :

```
public slots:
    void GetDone(QNetworkReply*);
```

was not matching actual function :

```
void GetHTMLSource::GetDone(QNetworkReply* ReplyIn)
{ ... }
```

However moving it to seperated .h and .cpp files probably helped.